# Image from Hyperlink in Typst?

Tags: image, url, typst

I'd like to embed an internet image in my presentation.

So far, I could not find a feature which allows me to enter a URL for that purpose.

This one does not work:

```
#figure(image("https://cdn.sstatic.net/Img/teams/teams-illo-free-sidebar-promo.svg?v=47faa659a05e"), caption: [Stack Overflow image])
```

It is looking for a local path in the current directory.

Or is it the reason that it does not work with the rendered PDF? Downloading and replacing the image link with a local path is likely not a functionality, isn't it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Typst does not do internet access for security reasons. It is, for all intents and purposes, sandboxed. You would have to download the image yourself and put it in a relative path to your project.

Absolute paths also don't work as-is for the same reasons, though there is the `--root` CLI option.